# What do you use to access CSV data on S3 and other object storage providers as a PyTorch Dataset?

Tags: amazon-s3, pytorch, google-cloud-storage, azure-blob-storage, object-storage

My dataset is stored as a collection of CSV files in an Amazon Web Services (AWS) Simple Storage Service (S3) bucket. I'd like to train a PyTorch model based on this data but the built-in Dataset classes do not provide native support for object storage services like S3 or Google Cloud Storage (GCS), Azure Blob storage, and such. I checked the PyTorch documentation here https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html# about the available Dataset classes and it comes up short when it comes to public cloud object storage support.

It looks like I have to create my own custom Dataset according to the following instructions: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html#dataset-class but the effort seems overwhelming: I need to figure out how to download data from the object storage to local node, parse the CSV files to read them into PyTorch tensors, and then deal with the possibility of running out of disk space since my dataset is 100s of GBs.

Since PyTorch models are trained using gradient descent and I only need to store just a small batch of data (less than 1GB) in memory at once, is there a custom dataset implementation that can help?

Answer (score 1):

Check out ObjectStorage Dataset which has support for object storage services like S3 and GCS [osds.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gcs.html](http://osds.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gcs.html)

You can run

```
pip install osds
```

to install it and then point it at your S3 bucket to instantiate the PyTorch Dataset and DataLoader using something like

```
from osds.utils import ObjectStorageDataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader


ds = ObjectStorageDataset(f"gcs://gs://cloud-training-demos/taxifare/large/taxi-train*.csv", 
 storage_options = {'anon' : False }, 
 batch_size = 32768, 
 worker = 4, 
 eager_load_batches = False)

dl = DataLoader(ds, batch_size=None)
```

where you use your S3 location path instead of `gcs://gs://cloud-training-demos/taxifare/large/taxi-train*.csv`. So your glob for S3 would be something like `s3://<bucket name>/<object path>/*.csv` depending on the bucket and the bucket directory where you store your CSV objects for the dataset.